# Libreoffice file locking issues in 19.04, no problems in 18.10

Tags: libreoffice, 19.04

Libreoffice 6.2.2.2 20(Build:2) hangs on 19.04 with "Loading document.." on some but not all ODTs. I had no issues on 18.10. Note that I had removed the hidden lock files in the directory.

It was no linux file permission issue:

```
ls -l *odt
-rw-r--r-- 1 me me 160558 Aug 13  2018 fails.odt
-rw-r--r-- 1 me me  16466 Apr 22 22:32 works.odt
```

After removing /home/username/.config/libreoffice the problem goes away. Why was the file locked? Did something go wrong in the installation?

For the record:
My fresh 19.04/Libreoffice gave me several warnings and errors, "failed to read path from javaldx", and locked up. I purged the Libreoffice installation and removed the config directory, and even installed java* as advised by the command-line messages.... very messy.

Comment: Can you still reproduce the problem?

Comment: Yes, it got worse! I now have to delete the config directory frequently, it seems every time I open or create a file. Otherwise a window pops up telling me "Soffice is not responding".

Answer (score 0):

I had issues too with Libre Office not starting after the 19.04 upgrade. I fully uninstalled Libre Office, restarted and reinstalled and it seems to be working again:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge libreoffice*
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autorermove

reboot

sudo apt-get install libreoffice
```

Comment: Tks Reuben, but I had tried this in vain before. I have just sibmitted a bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libreoffice/+bug/1826757

Answer (score 0):

Note that my problem is fixed when using 6.3.0.0.alpha1, god bless!

The issue with slow loading ODT remains in LO 6.2.3.2 and I have submitted this follow-up https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=125426.